# roscd not woring

Tags: ros, catkin, roscd, source, setup.bash

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all.

I've been trying to get back into ROS but I keep having this issue of roscd not finding catkin_ws. I went as far as removing the catkin_ws folder and copying everything from the Catkin tutorial on how to setup a workspace but still the same results.
These are the steps I took:

```
david@davidsPro3:~$ source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash

david@davidsPro3:~$ mkdir -p ~/catkin_ws/src

david@davidsPro3:~$ cd ~/catkin_ws/src

david@davidsPro3:~/catkin_ws/src$ catkin_init_workspace

Creating symlink "/home/david/catkin_ws/src/CMakeLists.txt" pointing to "/opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake"
david@davidsPro3:~/catkin_ws/src$ cd ~/catkin_ws/
david@davidsPro3:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/david/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/david/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/david/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/david/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/david/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/david/catkin_ws/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/david/catkin_ws/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/david/catkin_ws/install -G Unix Makefiles" in "/home/david/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.4
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.4
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/david/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/indigo
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/indigo
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "2.7.6") 
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/david/catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Looking for include file pthread.h
-- Looking for include file pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.6.18
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/david/catkin_ws/build
####
#### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/david/catkin_ws/build"
####

david@davidsPro3:~/catkin_ws$ source devel/setup.bash

david@davidsPro3:~/catkin_ws$ echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

/home/david/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks

david@davidsPro3:~/catkin_ws$
```

Once done I opened a new terminal and ran roscd with the results below:

```
david@davidsPro3:~$ roscd catkin_ws

roscd: No such package/stack 'catkin_ws'

david@davidsPro3:~$ 

david@davidsPro3:~$ roscd

david@davidsPro3:/opt/ros/indigo$
```

I also did this followed by sourcing

```
Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/david/catkin_ws/build"
```

Thanks for and help and suggestions on why this is not working?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239650/roscd-not-woring/) by [MiniMe](https://answers.ros.org/users/22450/minime/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2016-07-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chrissi](https://answers.ros.org/users/15386/chrissi/) on 2016-07-16**:
Doesn't roscd only work on package? catkin_ws is a workspace not a package.

**Comment by [MiniMe](https://answers.ros.org/users/22450/minime/) on 2016-07-17**:
Not sure why things were not working originally when I was trying to roscd to beginner_tutorials as I was doing everything in one terminal and I was sourcing at the end. Regardless it is working now (I assume I was mistyping something).
Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check [this](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbash#roscd) for roscd.
The roscd command works fine. Roscd allows you to change directories using a package name, stack name, or special location.

```
roscd: No such package/stack 'catkin_ws'
```

The catkin_ws you are trying to find with the roscd is not a package, but contains packages if you have built some.
So if in your catkin_ws/src directory are built packages you can roscd them.

Don't forget, after each build you do at your workspace (catkin_make) to source the devel/setup.bash to have better use of the roscd command.

---

Originally posted by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) with karma: 354 on 2016-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0